# How to calculate the size of a BitSet in bytes?

Tags: java, huffman-code, bitset

I used a Java `BitSet` to encode a message.

My compressed file size comes out to 954kb, but when I do `BitSet.cardinality()`, I get around 4mb. Can you explain this?

Comment: Can you show your code please? How did you "fill" the `BitSet`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`BitSet.cardinality()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#cardinality()) returns the number of bits set to `true` in the `BitSet`. I think you are looking for [`BitSet.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size()). But keep in mind it will return the number of *bits*, not *bytes*.

Assuming after Huffman encoding you have approximately half of the bits set to `true`, that means your `BitSet` should have a size of around 4.000.000*2 = 8.000.000 bits in your `BitSet` which in turn makes around 1.000.000 bytes which is rather close to the 954kb you see.

This should explain your observation.